# Find the count of -1 in each column

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a pandas data frame. Some entries are equal to -1. How to find the number of times -1 exist in every column in the data frame. Based on that count, I am planning to drop the column.

Comment: You want the result for each column separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say you want the result for each column separately, you can use the condition like - `df[column] == -1` , and then take `.sum()` on the result of the condition to get the count of `-1` values for that row. Example -

```
(df[column] == -1).sum()
```

Demo -

```
In [22]: df
Out[22]:
   A  B  C
0 -1  2 -1
1  3  4  5
2  3  1  4
3 -1  2  1

In [23]: for col in df.columns:
   ....:     print(col, (df[col] == -1).sum())
   ....:
A 2
B 0
C 1
```

This works because when taking `sum()` , `True` value is equivalent to `1` and `False` is equivalent to `0`. And the condition `df[column] == -1` returns a Series of `True/False` values, `True` where the condition is met and `False` where the condition is not met.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could have tried a few things before asking here, but I might as well post the answer anyway:

```
(df == -1).sum()
```

Ironically you can't use the `count()` method of a `DataFrame` because that counts all values except for `None` or `nan`, and there's no way to change the criterion. It's easier to just use `sum` than to figure out a way to convert the `-1`s to `None`s.